# htaccess rewrite rule, old URL to new

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

A bit of help fellow SO people.

What I have at the moment (based on some code I used for a different type of URL).

I want the first URL to redirect to the second, with no query string included afterwards

This is what I have to so far.

```
RewriteRule ^(page.php?id=missionstatement+)/?$ http://example.com/why/mission-statement [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(page.php?id=ofsted+)/?$ http://example.com/how/ofsted-report [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(page.php?id=governingbody+)/?$ http://example.com/governors [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That's wrong -- RewriteRule does not work with query string like that. Could you please show the URL and how it should be redirected (from URL => to URL) as these some of the "characters" that you have put into your rules confusing me A LOT.

Comment: http://example.com/page.php?id=whatever => http://example.com/how/something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the rule (will redirect 1 URL):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=whatever
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/how/somehow? [R=301,L]
```

1. This rule intended to be placed in .htaccess in website root folder. If placed elsewhere some small tweaking may be required.
2. I have used `%{HTTP_HOST}` -- this will redirect to the same domain as requested URL. If domain name has to be different, replace it by exact domain name.
3. The `?` at the end of new URL will get rid of existing query string.

Comment: Woop. Thanks for the explanations as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ahoy!

Give this a whirl:

```
#check mod_rewrite is enabled
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

#enable mod rewrite
RewriteEngine On

#set working directory
RewriteBase /

#force trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

#bootstrap index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^page.php\?id=(.*)$ http://www.willans.com/page.php/$1 [R=310,L]

#end mod rewrite check
</IfModule>
```

It's been a while since i've done any web dev, but that should be a push in the right direction at least ;)